# Continuous function with real numbers and rational numbers....

Tags: general-topology

I know if I consider real numbers with topology which generated by [a,b) there is a continuous function from  R onto rational numbers with usual topology. Also, I know there is a continuous function from irrational numbers with usual topology onto integers.

My question, wether or not a continuous function from rational number( with usual topology) into Integers,

Comment: Do you mean "onto"?

Comment: Yes Just I forgot I mean onto because constant always  exists

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want "onto", let $\alpha$ be irrational and try $f(x) = \lfloor x-\alpha \rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

For any irrational $x$, the function $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}$ that maps a rational number that lies in the interval $(-x+2kx,x+2kx)$ to $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is locally constant ($\iff$ continuous since the codomain is discrete) and onto.